# Is there a way to add custom X-headers to the outbound emails?

Tags: header

We have been using SFMC Partner API web service to trigger emails. We basically use Triggered Send definitions. Would like to know if we can add custom X-headers to the outbound emails like header.add("UniqueID","1111-2222-3333").

We need this to track bounced emails and take necessary actions. If an email is bounced, the idea is to read the UniqueID x-header to determine the bounced email uniquely.

Comment: Did you ever find anything? I'm trying to add `X-MC-*` headers for Mandrill emails https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582117-How-to-Use-SMTP-Headers-to-Customize-Your-Messages.